How to layout interposer?
I need to make an interposer to sit on a QFN pads. I think i want to make small BGA-like balls over the QFN pads.
How do I do it and what do I need to know?

why not have them just be regular QFN style pads and attach it with solder paste like a normal QFN? This is basically what an LQFN is.

It's an option, but I am not sure we will be able to apply solder through a mask, so balls seem a better idea

Even with balls on the QFN, you still need to apply paste to the board it's being soldered to.
